# ViewModel constructor containing arguments ins WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

How can we bind a user-control to a view-model object, when this last contains parameters in his constructor ???

Does the binding using "DataContext" in the view ensure that when we create a view-model, the view is automatically created ??

Comment: What do you mean? are you using IoC containers? if yes which ones? please provide us with some more information ...

Comment: I didn't find any solution to that ! I'm just asking how to bind a view to a viewModel which contains parameters in the constructor... can you show me any simple example using the IoC containers please ?

Comment: All of my ViewModels take constructor parameters.  Type registration and Instance registration at module load time determines how the parameters are constructed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IoC container, this is supported out-of-the-box.

It really depends on the IoC container you are using, but here is an example using Prism Unity container.

The following examples are taken out from the [Prism QuickStarts guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28950)

So, at first, we will have to set up the unity container:

```
public class QuickStartBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
   private readonly CallbackLogger callbackLogger = new CallbackLogger();

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the <see cref="IUnityContainer"/>. 
    ///May be overwritten in a derived class to add specific
    /// type mappings required by the application.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        // Here you can do custom registeration of specific types and instances
        // For example
        this.Container.RegisterInstance<CallbackLogger>(this.callbackLogger);

        base.ConfigureContainer();
    }
}
```

Baisically, youre done!
All you have to do now is have your view recieve the viewModel as a parameter in his constructor, like this:

```
public partial class OverviewView
{
    public OverviewView(OverviewViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Unity IoC container will take care of your parameters in the ViewModel even without you having to register those types most of the times.

Please note that in my answer I only refered to the IoC part of the configuration. setting up an entire MVVM application requires a bit more work and varies depending the MVVM framework you are using